# Returning the argument of a function if the argument is not of the right type

Tags: functions, attributes

Best to give an example. Let us consider the function `AdjacencyMatrix`. When we pass, say a matrix to it, we get:

```
test = {{1,1,1},{1,2,2},{3,3,3}};
AdjacencyMatrix[%]
```

> AdjacencyMatrix::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in AdjacencyMatrix[{{1,1,1},{1,2,2},{3,3,3}}].

`AdjacencyMatrix[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}]`

Is there a way of modifying `AdjacencyMatrix` so that if the argument isn't a graph object it would simply return the argument itself?

Comment: You want `AdjacencyMatrix` to return the argument itself only when it is a matrix, or whenever it is not a graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check) in a user defined function:

```
adjacencyMatrix[g_] := Check[AdjacencyMatrix[g], g]
```

Then:

```
adjacencyMatrix[Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->4}]] //Normal
adjacencyMatrix[{1->2, 2->3, 3->4}] //Normal
adjacencyMatrix[{{1,2},{3,4}}]
```

> {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
>
> {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
>
> AdjacencyMatrix::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in AdjacencyMatrix[{{1,2},{3,4}}].
>
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Comment: This is much better than my approach. Note: OP may want to suppress the error message here: `Quiet[Check[...], {AdjacencyMatrix::graph}]`.

Answer (score 4):

Bad answer:

```
Unprotect[AdjacencyMatrix];
AdjacencyMatrix[mat_List] := mat
Protect[AdjacencyMatrix];
```

Good answer:

```
adjacencyMatrix[graph_Graph] := AdjacencyMatrix[graph]
adjacencyMatrix[mat_List] := mat
```

Comment: For the good answer, maybe remove the pattern head `List` on the second line, as this is the behavior requested for anything that's not a `Graph`.

Comment: @Roman good point. Let me ask OP to be sure. (If they only want the identity for matrices, then it is safer to leave `List` in).